# How do I setup Tailwind CSS with Sails.js?

Tags: sails.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to setup [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/) with [Sails.js](https://sailsjs.com/), but haven't found working instructions online. How do I do this?

Comment: See if this helps: https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/issues/451

Comment: I found https://github.com/tailwindlabs/discuss/issues/180 which is inconclusive